# php5 and namespace?

Tags: php, namespaces

I work a lot in PHP but I never really understand the namespace method in PHP. Can somebody help me here? I have read on php.net's website its not explained good enough, and I can't find examples on it.

I need to know how I can make code in sample version.

- namespace: sample

  - class: sample_class_1

    - function: test_func_1
  - class: sample_class_2

    - function: test_func_2
    - function: test_func_3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this?

```
<?php

namespace sample
{
    class Sample_class_1
    {
        public function test_func_1($text)
        {
            echo $text;
        }
    }

    class Sample_class_2
    {
        public static function test_func_2()
        {
            $c = new Sample_class_1();
            $c->test_func_1("func 2<br />");
        }

        public static function test_func_3()
        {
            $c = new Sample_class_1();
            $c->test_func_1("func 3<br />");
        }
    }
}

// Now entering the root namespace...
//  (You only need to do this if you've already used a different
//   namespace in the same file)
namespace
{
    // Directly addressing a class
    $c = new sample\Sample_class_1();
    $c->test_func_1("Hello world<br />");

    // Directly addressing a class's static methods
    sample\Sample_class_2::test_func_2();

    // Importing a class into the current namespace
    use sample\Sample_class_2;
    sample\Sample_class_2::test_func_3();
}

// Now entering yet another namespace
namespace sample2
{
    // Directly addressing a class
    $c = new sample\Sample_class_1();
    $c->test_func_1("Hello world<br />");

    // Directly addressing a class's static methods
    sample\Sample_class_2::test_func_2();

    // Importing a class into the current namespace
    use sample\Sample_class_2;
    sample\Sample_class_2::test_func_3();
}
```

If you're in another file you don't need to call `namespace {` to enter the root namespace. So imagine the code below is another file "ns2.php" while the original code was in "ns1.php":

```
// Include the other file
include("ns1.php");

// No "namespace" directive was used, so we're in the root namespace.

// Directly addressing a class
$c = new sample\Sample_class_1();
$c->test_func_1("Hello world<br />");

// Directly addressing a class's static methods
sample\Sample_class_2::test_func_2();

// Importing a class into the current namespace
use sample\Sample_class_2;
sample\Sample_class_2::test_func_3();
```

Comment: Okai, so i need to use "namespace" before i using items in the namespace?

Comment: i ask becures i want the namespace call indsite a class i have right now when i need to use this namespace like a fremawork, :)

Comment: The way it works is, every class (and function, and variable) lives inside a namespace. If you don't use the "namespace" keyword it assumes you're in the root namespace. If you want to use items from a different namespace (for example a class from "sample" when you're in "sample_2" or in the root) you have to either address it by its full name (for example `sample\Sample_class_1`) or import it into your current namespace (using `use "sample\Sample_class_1";`)